# expected type parameter `T`, found struct `Cmd`

Tags: generics, rust, traits

New to rust , I've been messing around with traits using Rust and I've come across a problem. Here's some code:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
pub struct Cluster<T> {
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}

pub trait AAAA {
    fn test();
}
pub struct Cmd {}
impl AAAA for Cmd {
    fn test() {}
}
impl<T: AAAA> Cluster<T> {
    pub fn dispatch_to(&self, addr: &str, cmd: T) {

    }
    pub fn auth(&self, auth: &str) {
        let cmd = Cmd{};
        self.dispatch_to("test", cmd);
    }
}
```

This produces the errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/test.rs:19:34
   |
13 | impl<T: AAAA> Cluster<T> {
   |      - this type parameter
...
19 |         self.dispatch_to("test", cmd);
   |              -----------         ^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found struct `Cmd`
   |              |
   |              arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                      found struct `Cmd`
note: associated function defined here
  --> src/test.rs:14:12
   |
14 |     pub fn dispatch_to(&self, addr: &str, cmd: T) {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^                    ------
```

Cmd is impl AAAA, why error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to with the trait `AAAA`. You will get the same error with:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
pub struct Cluster<T> {
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}

pub struct Cmd {}

impl<T> Cluster<T> {
    pub fn dispatch_to(&self, addr: &str, cmd: T) {}
    pub fn auth(&self, auth: &str) {
        self.dispatch_to("test", Cmd {});
    }
}
```

Let's for a moment assume the compiler allows the above code to compile.
We'll get a better understanding when we use this type in an example.

```
fn main() {
  let c = Cluster::<i32> {
    _marker: PhantomData,
  }; // here T is i32

  c.auth("abc"); // but here `Cmd` is being forced as `i32`
}
```

You see the problem? The `Cluster` was instantiated as `Cluster<i32>`, but the `auth()` function is forcing `Cmd` type to be treated as `i32` or any other type the `Cluster` is parametrized over, so there's clearly a conflict and hence the compiler cries foul. This process is called monomorphization where the `T` is determined at the compile time.

So in your case, you should parametrize over `dispatch_to()` function.

i.e replace

```rust
pub fn dispatch_to (&self, addr: &str, cmd: T) {}
```

with

```rust
pub fn dispatch_to<R: AAAA>(&self, addr: &str, cmd: R) {}
```

Comment: but I can not change dispatch_to func in my project for now ,  it means I must write another dispatch_to_ext<R: AAAA>(&self, addr: &str, cmd: R) ?

Comment: yes. that or [don't call](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9041c1dfd590f0efe7799efa91c5277) `dispatch_to()` from `auth()`